# 500 - Internal server error.when uploading asp.net core to godaddy

Tags: shared-hosting, asp.net-core-1.1

site does work when I upload it onto [azure Server](http://gtaconnections.azurewebsites.net/) but it doesn't when I use [GoDaddy](http://gtaconnections.ca/). I have contacted GoDaddy's support but these guys are completely clueless in to what's wrong. Here's a link to my [OneDrive folder](https://1drv.ms/f/s!Aly_kaDAbD99hKQBpV2ZRZmnUdmPbA) that should contain the same thing that is on the server

Comment: Check with GoDaddy whether they support .net core. I', also assuming you configured to display the error rather than a generic page

Comment: apparently they do support .net core